# State does not get updated immediately in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been trying to update my states in parent component which will be initiated from child.

I'm passing a method as props in child and calling that method in child.

So that I can update two of my states in parent. Please take a look at the method: it's in parent component.

```
const onImageSelected = (img, imgId) => {
    // console.log(img) shows img
    // console.log(imgId) shows imgId
    setCoverImage(img) // I can use this img in my parent component as src(it's actually an image path)
    setBrandPage({...brandPage, cover_photo: imgId}) // but this state is not updating with imgId in the "cover_photo" field of brandPagte state. brandPage state is holding the previous value)
    setFormData({...formData, brand_page:brandPage})
}
```

please take a look at the comments of the code above. Why my brandPage state is not updating but coverImage is updating.

Can someone help me solve that ?

Comment: Can you make a minimal, reproducible example using codesandbox?

Comment: @slideshowp2 Thanks for your comment. I found the solution in Laxminarayan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to access new state immediately after setting, new State will not available as setState function is asynchronous.

Make copy of brandPage and use it

```
const newBrandPage = {...brandPage, cover_photo: imgId}
setBrandPage(newBrandPage)
setFormData({...formData, brand_page:newBrandPage})
```

Comment: Thank you so much my man, It's working. but one thing I don't understand is that Why coverImage is getting updated and brandPage is not.

Comment: both were getting updated but while setting formdata brandPage was still holding old values

Comment: I console logged brandPage.cover_photo it was showing the old data.
same with with formData.brand_page.cover_photo. 

it's something that is confusing. why coverImage is getting updated? @Laxminarayan Nayak

Comment: console.log() executes before setState function execution, thats why you see old data. rerender happens once setState function executed